# Gradle (Kotlin DSL): "Unresolved reference: proguard"

Tags: gradle, proguard, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Im trying to get Proguard to work but Im still new to Gradle.
My build gradle.kts haves an error (Unresolved reference: proguard), I cant create a proguard Task:

```
plugins {
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "5.2.0"
    java
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.61"
}

group = "*...*"
version = "*...*"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter() 
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    //*...*
    implementation("net.sf.proguard","proguard-gradle","6.2.2") //is this correct?
}

configure<JavaPluginConvention> {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    jar{
        manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "*...*"
        }
    }

    shadowJar{
        archiveBaseName.set("*...*")
        archiveClassifier.set("")
        archiveVersion.set("")
    }



    register<proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask>("myProguardTask") { //Unresolved reference: proguard

    }


}
```

This is *not* an Android Project
Because Stackoverflow wants me to write more than just code: Im planing to somehow link the proguard output to the shadowjar task. If you know how to do it Im also interested to that (and I could not try it myself because of this problem).

Comment: If you want to use the ProguardTask in a gradle script, you need to add the proguard dependency to the buildscript environment rather than adding it as a project dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared a dependency of proguard in project rather than for Gradle itself.

Move the dependency to the [`buildscript`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:build_script_external_dependencies) block:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.2.2'
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to create your task.

---

Alternatively, you can declare the repository in `settings.gradle.kts`:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

which will trim down the `buildscript` block in `build.gradle.kts`:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.2.2")
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first solution haves already worked for me but your last example is Groovy instead of Kotlin DSL, right? The > classpath 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.2.2' < part.